# understanding level =0 and group_keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas groupby and finding size for ex:

```
dd=df.groupby(['value','year','team']).size()
```

and it giving me output as:

```
value  year  team
0      2000  B       2
1      2000  A       2
       2001  A       1
2      2001  B       1
3      2001  A       2
```

my question is what is level =0 and group_keys (given below )which is applying on grouped dataframe dd.

```
ddf3=dd.groupby(level=0,group_keys=False).apply(function).reset_index()
```

is (level=0) be 'value' column in grouped dataframe dd.

Please help me.

Comment: level=0 mean the the index value

Comment: which column refers level=0 in the above grouped dataframe dd

Comment: index name value is level=0

Comment: Thanks for your Response . You mean column value will level 0 ,column year will level 1 etc

Comment: Yes, and also that is not column , that is multiple index, when yu type df.index, you will seems the para level ,this where level 0 and level 1 come from

Answer (score 19):

```
df.groupby(level=0)
```

It specifies the first index of the `Dataframe`. When you have multiple indices and you need to `groupby` only one index of those multiple indices of the dataframe we use it.

It means:

- level 0 -> First Index
- level 1 -> Second Index
- etc..

Comment: Might be worth stating that using `level=-1` specifies the rightmost, or outermost index.

Answer (score 6):

The level in `groupby()` is used when you have multiple indices and you want to use only one index of the DataFrame.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'values':0,'year':2000,'team':'A'}, 
                   {'values':1,'year':2000,'team':'B'}, 
                   {'values':2,'year':2001,'team':'B'}
                  ])
df = df.groupby(['values','year','team']).size()
df
```

Output:

> ```
> values  year  team
> 0       2000  A       1
> 1       2000  B       1
> 2       2001  B       1
> ```

```
df = df.groupby(level=1).size()
df
```

Output:

> ```
> year
> 2000    2
> 2001    1
> ```